# Figure caption font in Classic Thesis

Tags: fonts, classicthesis

I am trying to change the font of the caption of my thesis, written with the packages ClassicThesis and Ars Classica.

At the moment, the bold "Figure x:" is written in Iwona font, while the rest with the same font as the text. I would like to change that to be Iwona as well.

I have tried with the caption package, or the \setkomafont{caption} command, but with no luck so far as I can't find a command for this particular font.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please, provide small, complete document beginning with `\documentclass{...}`, add used package, which are necessary to demonstrate your problem and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is as easy as adding `\captionsetup{font=sf}`:

```
\documentclass[
  10pt,
  a4paper,
  twoside,
  openright,
  titlepage,
  fleqn,
  headinclude,
  footinclude,
  BCOR5mm,
  numbers=noenddot,
  cleardoublepage=empty,
  tablecaptionabove
]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[pdfspacing]{classicthesis}
\usepackage{arsclassica}

\captionsetup{font=sf}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Title}

Some text

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
\fbox{\rule{0pt}{1cm}\rule{1cm}{0pt}}
\caption{The caption to the table}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering
\caption{The caption to the table}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\hline
a & a\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great, thank you very much! Just out of curiosity: in the command, "sf" stands for what?

Comment: @SamueleGrandi It's customary lingo for “sans serif” (like in `\sffamily`).